# Synonymize [subdirectory], [subdirectories], [subdirs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I propose to synonymize these three tags:

- [subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory) (541 questions)
- [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) (249 questions)
- [subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirs) (16 questions)

Probably the currently largest tag (subdirectory) should become the master tag.

Comment: I would argue all three of those tags should be deleted.

Comment: Can anyone be an expert in subd... arh, never mind.

Comment: If we do keep them, we should somehow pun-group them into a single subdirectory. But I think I'm with @cpburnz in saying we should delete them.

Comment: Maybe "*Should we make [subdirectories] and [subdirs] subdirectories of [subdirectory]?*"

Comment: There are also [folder] variants that may need the same treatment

Answer (score 12):

I have a issue with this proposal. And it comes in the figure of a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/35323161/792066

(newest question when I started writing this answer)

The [subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory), out of 541 questions, [310 have no language tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory%20not%20php%20not%20wordpress%20not%20git%20not%20python%20not%20c%23%20not%20java%20not%20c%20not%20ruby-on-rails%20not%20ruby%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.2%20not%20rubygems%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.1%20not%20rubymine%20not%20ruby-on-rails-plugins%20not%20ruby-on-rails-2%20not%20rubymotion%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.2%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.1%20not%20ruby-1.9.3%20not%20ruby-2.0%20not%20ruby-1.9%20not%20ruby-datamapper%20not%20ruby-1.9.2%20not%20ruby-1.8.7%20not%20ruby-2.1%20not%20c%2B%2B%20not%20perl?mode=all) (the most popular were: php, wordpress, git, python, c#, java, c, ruby*, c++, perl), 53% of the total. [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) is slightly more, 54% ([136 out 249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories%20not%20php%20not%20wordpress%20not%20git%20not%20python%20not%20c%23%20not%20java%20not%20c%20not%20ruby-on-rails%20not%20ruby%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.2%20not%20rubygems%20not%20ruby-on-rails-3.1%20not%20rubymine%20not%20ruby-on-rails-plugins%20not%20ruby-on-rails-2%20not%20rubymotion%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.2%20not%20ruby-on-rails-4.1%20not%20ruby-1.9.3%20not%20ruby-2.0%20not%20ruby-1.9%20not%20ruby-datamapper%20not%20ruby-1.9.2%20not%20ruby-1.8.7%20not%20ruby-2.1%20not%20c%2B%2B%20not%20perl?mode=all)). Most of these can and should be closed using off topic > general computing without a second thought. So I propose that we retag this from [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) to [cleanup](/questions/tagged/cleanup)[burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

Comment: Thanks for the research on it

Answer (score 7):

All of these tags should be subdirectories of `/dev/null`.

Honestly, nuke 'em. From orbit. With lightness racing…

Comment: inb4 _`/dev/null` is a "file" not a directory and cannot have subdirectories_ shutup.png

Comment: At the very least, they can simply be synonymized to [tag:directory].